# .Net Core 3.0 executable doesn't read appsettings.json

Tags: c#, .net-core, config, app-config

I'm writing a simple .Net Core 3.0 console application and publishing as a single executable.

I figured out how to exclude the `appsettings.json` file, but when I run the application it uses the original settings and doesn't honor changes I make to the `appsettings.json file.

Perhaps when I run the executable it is copying the original `appsettings.json` file to a temp folder somewhere and reading that rather than the file at the original location?

If so, where is that temp location when running on Debian Linux?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    private static MySettings settings = new MySettings();

    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
        .Build();

    config.GetSection("Settings").Bind(settings);

    rootPath = settings.RootPath;
}

public class MySettings
{ 
    public int Buffer { get; set; }
    public string RootPath { get; set; }
    public int FrequencySeconds { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I improved formatting and added relevant tags

Comment: How do you read the appsettings.json?

Comment: I've updated the post to show relevant portion of the code

Comment: @Matthew Show same of settings file

Comment: @Matthew Also try settings working directory `.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())`

Answer (score 6):

Try setting the base path to the working directory

```
.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
```

Also, the binding can be done using [`.Get<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?view=aspnetcore-2.2#bind-to-an-object-graph) on the section

```
static void Main(string[] args) {    

    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) //<--
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
        .Build();

    MySettings settings = config.GetSection("Settings").Get<MySettings>();

    rootPath = settings.RootPath;
}
```

Comment: `.net core 3.1`: 'ConfigurationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'SetBasePath' and no accessible extension method 'SetBasePath' accepting a first argument of type 'ConfigurationBuilder' could be found ...

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu make sure you have the necessary library referenced https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileconfigurationextensions.setbasepath?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1